# CakePHP 3.6.11: Update value in table

Tags: php, cakephp, model-view-controller, cakephp-3.0, cakephp-3.6

I have this tables:

> customers[id, name, surname, phone, text, balance, created]
>
> service_types[id, title, price, length, is_subscription, created]
>
> customer_service_types[id, customer_id, service_type_id, price, created]

When I add a new `customerServiceType` for a customer I want to update the `balance` of the customer accordingly using the given `price` value of the `customerServiceType`.

So here is what I have tried:

`CustomerServiceTypes/add.ctp`:

```
<fieldset>
        <legend><?= __('Add Customer Service Type') ?></legend>
        <?php
            echo $this->Form->control('customer_id', ['options' => $customers]);
            echo $this->Form->control('service_type_id', ['options' => $serviceTypes]);
            echo $this->Form->control('price');
        ?>
    </fieldset>
    <?= $this->Form->button(__('Submit')) ?>
    <?= $this->Form->end() ?>
```

`Model/Entity/CustomerServiceType.php`:

```
class CustomerServiceType extends Entity
{
//On create a new CustomerServiceType then update the selected customer's balance
    public function addCustomerServiceType($data = array()){
        $this->create;
        $this->save($data);

        //update customer balance
        $customer = $this->Customers->get($data['customerid']);

        $this->Customer->updateAll(
            array('Customer.balance' => 'Customer.balance + ' . $data['price']),
            array('Customer.id' => $data['customerid'])
        );

        return true;
    }
}
```

So in `CustomerServiceTypesController.php` I changed the `add()` like this:

```
public function add($customerid = null)
    {
        $customerServiceType = $this->CustomerServiceTypes->newEntity();
        if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            $customerServiceType = $this->CustomerServiceTypes->patchEntity($customerServiceType, $this->request->getData());
            if ($this->CustomerServiceType->addCustomerServiceType($this->request->data)) {
                $this->Flash->success(__('The customer service type has been saved.'));

                return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
            }
            $this->Flash->error(__('The customer service type could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
        }
        $customers = $this->CustomerServiceTypes->Customers->find('list', ['limit' => 200]);
        $serviceTypes = $this->CustomerServiceTypes->ServiceTypes->find('list', ['limit' => 200]);
        $this->set(compact('customerServiceType', 'customers', 'serviceTypes'));
    }
```

But I get this error:

> Call to a member function addCustomerServiceType() on boolean

And this notice:

> Undefined property: CustomerServiceTypesController::$CustomerServiceType

Comment: The first error is most likely caused because you are attempting to call a table that has not yet been loaded into the controller via `$this->loadModel()` and the notice is due to the fact that you cannot call entities like `$this->CustomerServiceType`, you would instead call `$customerServiceType->addCustomerServiceType()`. However as Mary has pointed out, there are much better approaches to this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want something to happen *after* saving data, I think you are better off using the `Model.afterSave` event: https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/table-objects.html#aftersave

#### In your Controller

```
$this->CustomerServiceTypes->save($customerServiceType)
```

#### In your Table Object `CustomerServiceTypesTable.php`

```
namespace App\Model\Table;

use Cake\ORM\Table;
use Cake\Event\Event;
use Cake\ORM\TableRegistry;
use ArrayObject;
use Cake\Datasource\EntityInterface;

class CustomerServiceTypesTable extends Table
{
    public function afterSave(Event $event, EntityInterface $entity, ArrayObject $options)
    {
        // only execute if the entity is new
        // if you want this to happen on edits too, remove this clause

        if ($entity->isNew()) {
            // get instance of the Customers table
            $customers = TableRegistry::getTableLocator()->get('Customers');

            $customer = $customers->get($entity->customerid);
            // do more stuff here
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Argument 2 passed to App\Model\Table\CustomerServiceTypesTable::beforeMarshal() must be an instance of App\Model\Table\EntityInterface, instance of ArrayObject given, called in C:\xampp\htdocs\bodytec_new_dev\vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\Event\EventManager.php on line 353

Comment: Sorry, my fault – should be `afterSave` instead of `beforeMarshal`. Updated the answer.

Comment: hmmm now I receive this error: Argument 2 passed to App\Model\Table\CustomerServiceTypesTable::afterSave() must be an instance of App\Model\Table\EntityInterface, instance of App\Model\Entity\CustomerServiceType given, called in C:\xampp\htdocs\bodytec_new_dev\vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\Event\EventManager.php on line 353

Comment: I ended up doing all the update action in the `add` function, but I would like to see your example working

Comment: Please add the classes that the `afterSave` function receives instances from by adding  `use ArrayObject;` and `use Cake\Datasource\EntityInterface;` to your table object.